# Multiple integer read in java with bufferedreader in java

Tags: java

I working on a program where I have to read about 10^6 integers.
I tried working with the scanner class however when i tried for 800000*3 inputs, it took around 12.38 seconds.
I also tried tried to work with the BufferedReader which actually worked faster but then it does not take the input i give as desired.

> For e.g. if I want to read 3 numbers separated with a space, three consecutive nextInt() would work, but such is not the case for BufferedReader, it accepts the space as a string and while parsing the  string into integer throws NumberFormatException exception.
>
> input e.g. "8347 394730 3487", all three numbers must be stored separately.
>
> code e.g

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String b=br.readLine();     
    int x=Integer.parseInt(b);
    b=br.readLine();        
    int x1=Integer.parseInt(b);
    b=br.readLine();        
    int x2=Integer.parseInt(b);
    System.out.println(x+x1+x2);
}
```

Also the numbers can be as large as 10^10.

So I need help in using BufferedReader for such input. Also if at all there is any other alternate but faster method for reading integers, will be good enough.

Thank you

Comment: `readLine()` then `string = string.split(" ");` then just store the numbers in a list?

Comment: Sigh. We cant tell you why your code doesn't work and how to fix it without seeing your code. And we won't do your homework.

Comment: It would be really kind if you would elaborate this.

Comment: @PiyushVishwakarma do you have "8347 394730 3487" in each line ?

Comment: Can you read in from a file, or must you input it by the user?

Comment: its an input from user and yes @Mehdi, each line contains similar input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get the String and then use this :

```
String[] numberList = yourString.split("\\s+");
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String num : numberList){
     myList.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
}
```

update* : please try this one

```
public class Answer {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> eachLineList = new ArrayList<String>();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String b = br.readLine();
    eachLineList.add(b.trim()); //Line 1 added to String list

    b = br.readLine();
    eachLineList.add(b.trim()); //Line 2 added to String list

    b = br.readLine();
    eachLineList.add(b.trim()); //List 3 added to String list

    String[] numbers;
    for (String line : eachLineList) {
        numbers = line.split("\\s+");
        if (numbers.length <= 1) {
            //means if there was one or less integer each line don't do anything
            break;
        } else {
            int intNum;
            int temp = 0;
            for (String num : numbers) {
                intNum = Integer.parseInt(num);
                temp += intNum;
            }
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
    }
}}
```

if you enter something like this "8347 394730 3487" in each line the sum will be return back to you ~

Comment: well you see that your answer might just work, but the problem still persist, excess code will slow down the output generation.

Comment: @PiyushVishwakarma this code is a business code, you can not avoid writing it, or else your program does not work and it is well written and It's not slow at all

Comment: in that case i will try it out

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try receiving it as a String.

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String b=br.readLine();                      
String[] token = b.split(" ");      //Split into String array by space
int[] num = new int[token.length];  //Create int array

for(int x=0; x<token.length; x++)
    num[x] = Integer.parseInt(token[x]);  //Store all string array into int array

for(int x=0; x<num.length; x++)           //Printing
    System.out.print(num[x] + " ");
```

Given your input in one line with spaces, the output is as follows:

**Output:8347 394730 3487**

Answer (score 0):

The `String.split(separator)` method can be used to split a string into an array of strings, with the `separator` regex providing the separator.  Refer to the `String` and `Pattern` javadoc for the complete description.

---

However, if you are really concerned about performance, you could potentially reduce the time even further by using `String.indexOf` and `String.substring` to extract the numbers for parsing.  Or potentially parse them yourself to avoid the overhead of creating strings.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can check below code once.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String []b=br.readLine().split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(b[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the answer somehow, with a little help from stackoverflow ofcourse

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String b=br.readLine();     
    String[] numbers=b.split(" ");
    long[] x=new long[numbers.length];
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
    {
        x[i]=Long.parseLong(numbers[i]);
        System.out.println(x[i]);
    }
```